# Is it faster to POST data to a webmethod or dump client-side data to a server control and then get the data server-side?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a page that contains a jquery array used to store data client-side.

```
var idsOfSelectedRows = [];
```

When it's time to postback I'm trying to figure out if it's better to use AJAX and POST the data to a webmethod:

```
<asp:Button ID="submit" OnClientClick="SubmitOrderNumbers();" />

function SubmitOrderNumbers() {
  $.ajax({
    mtype: 'POST',
    postData: {
        orderNums: idsOfSelectedRows
    },
  });
}
```

Or dump the data to a control (hidden field) and then pick it back up server-side.

```
<asp:Button ID="submit"OnClientClick="DumpOrdersArray();" OnClick=Submit_Click />
```

Comment: Ajax will always be faster as it will only send the exact data you set, a postBack for controls will send a lot more data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using AJAX will usually be faster than POST because less data is sent through in AJAX than POST.

Note:  You shouldn't only base your solution on the speed of the call.